# Changing index sum of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}$$.

Now let $f(x)$ be uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$

Show that $$\int_0^\pi f(x) \,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2k+1)^4}$$

I'm not sure how to get past from this point. I was trying to move the index from n=0 but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried to "pull" 1 out and start at n=0, but I ended up with an undefined series (n^4 in the denominator).

---

$$\int_0^\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}\,dx
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\int_0^\pi\sin(nx) dx
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(\pi n)}{n^4}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(nx)dx=\dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\cdot\dfrac{-1}{n}\cos(nx)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\pi}=\dfrac{-1}{n^{4}}\left((-1)^{n}-1\right),
\end{align*}
now consider even and odd $n$ separately.

Comment: So when $n$ is even it results in 0. I'm unsure how to formulate it but it means we can only use odd numbers, so we let $n=2k+1$

Comment: Yes, so we let $n=2k+1$ for $k\geq 0$, then it is exactly the answer, no?

Comment: Yeah, I do however not see how you arrive to -1((-1)^n-1). It still makes perfect sense for -cos(pi*n)+1 though.

Comment: $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^{n}$ by induction for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Neat! I was not aware of that. Thanks